# WFS FeatureCollection to WFS-T

Tags: geoserver, wfs, wfs-t

I need to read WFS data from one GeoServer and insert it into another GeoServer, using code (C# in this case).

So I have a FeatureCollection, like this (real values masked):

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns= ...and so on... https://xxx.xx/xxxx/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=xxxx">
```

What is required to convert this into a WFS insert/update transaction? They seem very similar.

To sum it up: I need to get data from one GeoServer to another periodically, using code. The source I can only access using WFS. The destination runs in a Docker container. I can add to this docker image, maybe installing some tooling for the job, but I was thinking inserting the data with WFS-T was the simplest solution. Don't know for sure, though.

Comment: what have you tried so far? did you read the specification?

Comment: A WFS can provide GeoJSON, it's not an either/or comparison

Comment: I've read a LOT, so I'm looking for pointers so I'm at least going in the right direction. I can now create workspace and datastore using REST API (I don't have direct access to either GeoServer), and I'm wondering what I need to do to go from a WFS query result to a WFS transaction.

Comment: Updated question with 'to sum it up'.

Comment: Its not a problem to do it - what exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: I have only seen a few examples for WFS-T, so I'm not sure exactly how the format works. But you're saying it should be no problem inserting my WFS FeatureCollection to a GeoServer? I will go ahead and see how far I get. That's a direction, at least.

Comment: It's just a large bunch of text (maybe hundreds of MB) so just parsing it requires some knowledge. Changing the right tags, etc. I don't have any supporting tools so far.

Comment: Read the WFS spec (https://www.ogc.org/standards/wfs) - don't try to reverse engineer a published standard